# Why Find method generates a TOP(2) query?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 6.1, and I have a code like this:

```
Brand b;
using(var ctx = new KokosEntities())
{
      try
      {  
          b = ctx.Brands.Find(_brands[brandName].Id);
          return b;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
           _logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, ex);
      }
 }
```

And this generates:

```
 N'SELECT TOP (2) 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[OpenCartId] AS [OpenCartId]
FROM [dbo].[Brands] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @p0',N'@p0 int'
```

`Find` method returns a single result but it generates a `TOP(2)` query instead of `1`. Why?

Note: I'm sure I'm passing correct `Id` to the method, and yes, `Id` is the primary key.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [`DbSet<TEntity>.Find Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.113).aspx):

> Finds an entity with the given **primary key** values.

I took a peek at the source code for `Find` method and found:

```
/// <exception cref="T:System.InvalidOperationException">Thrown if multiple entities exist in the context with the primary key values given.</exception><exception cref="T:System.InvalidOperationException">Thrown if the type of entity is not part of the data model for this context.</exception><exception cref="T:System.InvalidOperationException">Thrown if the types of the key values do not match the types of the key values for the entity type to be found.</exception><exception cref="T:System.InvalidOperationException">Thrown if the context has been disposed.</exception>
    public virtual TEntity Find(params object[] keyValues)
    {
      return this.GetInternalSetWithCheck("Find").Find(keyValues);
    }
```

so the method will throw InvalidOperationException in case of multiple entities.

> Thrown if multiple entities exist in the context with the primary key
>   values given

Internally the call to `Find` doesn't translate into `Single/SingleOrDefault`; instead a simple loop is used to check for multiple entities.

**Since the method is specific to the primary key, it should throw an exception in case of multiple entities.** That is why it is generating a query to select at least two records. Similar to `Single` call.

Answer (score 10):

I'm guessing under the covers that gets converted to a `Single` call or something that looks like it. In that case, LINQ wants to make sure there is only 1 result. If there are 2 records returned, then it can throw.